# Usergrid does not run. Internal Server Error

Tags: ubuntu, usergrid

I'm trying to setup `Apache Usergrid` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. Im following [this deployment guide](https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/ug2-deploy-to-tomcat.html) I've got `Elasticsearch`, `Cassandra` and `Tomcat7` successfully running. I've configured properties file and put `ROOT.war` into `webapps` folder. However when I'm doing `curl http://localhost:8080/status` I'm receiving the following JSON:

> {"error":"uncaught","timestamp":1487258277314,"duration":0,"error_description":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.apache.usergrid.rest.exceptions.UncaughtException","error_id":"18972acc-f45b-11e6-87c0-b4b6760c611f"}

Can anybody shed a light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Excerpts from your log files, tcpdump traces, whatever else. Now the question looks like 'I got an uncaught exception, how can I fix it'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a particular version of `Cassandra`. namely 2.1

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide your hardware specs? Thanks.

Comment: hello. what exactly you want to know and why?

Comment: Just Ram and CPU specs. It is not running on my server with 1GB ram and 2.5 GHz CPU but running just fine on my personal computer with higher specs.

Comment: It was not my computer. I'll try to find out the specs and tell you